# Issue on Ubuntu 20.04 with SSL decryption and self-signed certificate

Tags: apt, 20.04, ssl

I am responsible for the security in our small company and one of our employees is using Ubuntu 20.10. He is currently testing SSL decryption (we use a Palo Alto FW) and he has had some issues with apt.

We use a self-signed certificate for the SSL decryption and he says he has added it as CA on his system like this:

- add them to  /etc/ca-certificates.conf
  #e.g.
  extra/cert_pa_root_selfsigned.crt
  extra/server_rootCA.crt
- sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
  (select the certs in gui)
- sudo update-ca-certificates

wget and apt both throw an error that there is a self-signed cert in the chain. It's getting a bit frustrating since possible solutions I provided to him were sometimes from older posts and he doesn't seem to be interested in trying it out because it's for older Ubuntu versions.

I am a bit in a dead end here, does anyone have a solution for Ubuntu 20.04 that works with self-signed certificates?

For Ubuntu 14.04 I found someone suggesting this:
Copy your *.crt file to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
run sudo update-ca-certificates

But another user commented for him it did not work because he is also using a self-signed cert, so I am reluctant to propose to try it. Unfortunately I do not have the possibility to test it myself on an Ubuntu system.

Thanks for any suggestions!